# Como imprimir renglones y columnas de una matriz c#?

Tags: c#, consola, studio, visual

Tengo un problema en el cual debo imprimir una matriz de calificaciones, sin embargo la parte debo imprimir el renglon 3 y la columna 2:

```
        int[,] calif = new int[4, 3];

        for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
            {
                Console.Write("Ingresa una calificacion: ");
                calif[r, c] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("TABLA DE CALIFICACIONES \n");
        for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
            {
                Console.Write(" " + calif[r, c]);

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Renglones y columnas: ");




        Console.ReadKey();
```

Les agradeceria si me ayudan con esta parte...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagínate que la tabla de calificaciones tiene lo siguiente:

```cs
//Una tabla de 4x3.

i0 -> 8  8  6
i1 -> 7  7  7
i2 -> 6  5  8
i3 -> 5  9  5
      ^  ^  ^
      |  |  |
      j0 j1 j2
```

La variable `i` representa el número de fila (el índice empieza a partir de `0`) y `j` representa el número de columna (también comienza a partir de `0`).

Por lo tanto, para poder imprimir los valores del renglón `3`, simplemente necesitaría recorrer toda la fila de `i3` (tal como lo muestra la tabla).

En código quedaría de esta forma:

```cs
for(int j = 0; j != 3; j++)
  Console.WriteLine(calif[3, j]);
```

El resultado por pantalla debería ser:

```cs
5  9  5
```

Lo mismo pasaría con la columna `2`, simplemente debemos imprimir los valores que estén en `j2` (tal como lo muestra la tabla de arriba).

En código sería:

```cs
for(int i = 0; i != 4; i++)
  Console.WriteLine(calif[i, 2]);
```

En pantalla debería salir lo siguiente:

```cs
6 7 8 5
```